# Why are multiple command-line terminal consoles available/running at the same time on RHEL systems?

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I'm studying for the RHCSA and am trying to wrap my mind around a seemingly basic concept: terminal consoles.  I don't understand how/why RHEL systems make 6 terminal consoles (`/dev/ttyN`) available for use.  If I'm managing a server (or workstation for that matter), under what circumstances would I want to hop between terminals (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)?

Wouldn't I just be connected to one terminal and work from there?

Answer (score 9):

For convenience. It lets multiple users log in on the console (e.g. you can have a console running as root and one as non-root). It lets you start an X session on one and have another with a text mode session, and yet another with an SVGA application. Apart from SVGA which isn't really relevant nowadays, having X or screen makes multiple consoles mostly redundant. But since the cost is tiny and it's occasionally useful, most distributions still have it as a default feature.